# Android DownloadManager - how to abort downloads?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I need to abort all failed/paused/pending/running downloads, but keep the successful ones. I think this is done with a DownloadManager Query, but I could not figure out how to write the code. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

We should call setFilterByStatus instead of setFilterById.

```
Button remove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove);
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterByStatus (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                while(c.moveToNext()) {
                    dm.remove(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)));
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

do this
downloadManager.remove(_yourdownloadID);

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `remove(downloadID...)` as per the docs says.

> Cancel downloads and remove them from the download manager. Each download will be stopped if it was running, and it will no longer be accessible through the download manager. If there is a downloaded file, partial or complete, it is deleted.

Docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#remove(long...)

```
Query query = new Query();    
query.setFilterById (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Cursor c = dm.query(query);
while(c.moveToNext()) {
    // Here you have all the downloades list which are running, failed, pending
    // and for abort your downloads you can call the `dm.remove(downloadsID)` to cancel and delete them from download manager.
    dm.remove(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)))
}
```

Comment: Yes, but from the Cursor c, how do I extract the IDs needed by the remove method?

Comment: When you call the method `enqueue` then it return you download ID. So you have to save those ID in your shared preferences for future calls related to those downloads.

Comment: I need to get the IDs from the c object, not from enqueue.

Comment: if that is the case, how good is the query? The query told us the pending/running/paused downloads. I need to remove only those.

Comment: From that you can get the list of downloads only not the ID, you should have ID in your case and simply call the `remove` method

Comment: I think I found it:      long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID))  ;
     downloadManager.remove(id) ;